# Adding together values from different association lists

Tags: associations

I have two association lists, whose values are integers, sharing some but not all keys.  For a small example, we might have

```
A=<|x->1, y->2, z->3|>;
B=<|y->-2, z->7, w->0|>;
```

I would like to "add" the two association lists, by adding values when they share a common key, but also I would like to drop any keys whose values are 0.  Thus, for my example I would want

`Add(A,B)=<|x->1, z->10|>;`

I can think of some ways to accomplish these tasks, but they are somewhat slow.  Any advice?

---

Edited to add:  In practice the list A is much longer than the list B, and has no zero values.  I'm going to replace A by Add(A,B) anyway, so it might be faster to update A using B in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it.

```
Merge[{A, B}, Total] // Select[# != 0 &]
(* <|x -> 1, z -> 10|> *)
```

If there are no 0 values in `A` you might want to remove the 0's from B before the `Merge`.

Answer (score 3):

Merge[{A, B}, Total] // DeleteCases@0